# Problem with Python's is None test?

Tags: python

I like using the *is None* test for empty variables, it's very flexible, easy and useful.  It seems to have stopped working now:

```
>"" is None
False

>[] is None
False

>{} is None
False
```

What's going on?

I'm using Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40) [GCC 4.4.5], on Debian/Sid i686 GNU/Linux.

Edit: Awesome tip from Sven Marnach of using bool("").  brb, off to edit some code...

Comment: This never should have worked...`is None` isn't for testing empty variables, it's for testing *precisely* if they are `None`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The test `x is None` tests if `x` really **is** the `None` object (that is, if the name `x` references the object `None`).  What you are looking for is [truth value testing](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

```
if "":
    print "non-empty"
else:
    print "empty"
```

`if` implicitly converts the condition to `bool`.  You can also explicitly do this:

```
>>> bool("")
False
>>> bool("x")
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Um... that never worked. `is` tests for instance identity -- even `{} is {}` is false.

```
>>> {} is {}
False
```

Answer (score 1):

It was never working. Only `None is None` is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Only `None` is `None`. I think what you are looking for is the boolean values of the empty `list`, `dict`, and `str`

For example:

```
>>> if "":
...     print 'woo'
... else:
...     print 'hoo'
...
hoo
```

Same for `{}` and `[]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply check on empty values it is better to use the following:

```
a = {}
b = []
c = ""

if a:
    print 'non-empty dict'
else:
    print 'empty dict'

if b:
    print 'non-empty list'
else:
    print 'empty list'

if c:
    print 'non-empty string/value'
else:
    print 'empty string/value'
```