# What is meant by "is not None" in python?

Tags: python-2.7

What is the difference between these two python idioms?

`if data is not None:
            return data`

`if data: return data`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497166/problem-with-pythons-is-none-test and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595/is-there-any-difference-between-foo-is-none-and-foo-none

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The latter will also reject `False`, `0`, `[]`, `()`, `{}`, `set()`, `''`, and any other value whose [`__bool__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) method returns False, including most empty collections.

The `None` value in Python is often used to indicate the lack of a value. It appears automatically when a function does not explicitly return a value.

```
>>> def f():
...   pass
>>> f() is None
True
```

It’s often used as the default value for optional parameters, as in:

```
def sort(key=None):
    if key is not None:
        # do something with the argument
    else:
        # argument was omitted
```

If you only used `if key:` here, then an argument which evaluated to false would not be considered. Explicitly comparing with `is None` is the correct idiom to make this check. See [Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).